# Does devise controller doesn't have access to database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm trying to implement coupon/token functionality. In `registration_controller.rb` I'm trying to find token/coupon by its code and assign referred user to another user's referrer, but it (coupon) returns me nil.

However if I insert byebug and copy paste code in console, it works perfectly. Any ideas why this is happening?

Also controller assign different user than it should (for example: New user should be assigned to user ID 3, but it assigns it to user ID 15)

```
def create
  unless params[:user][:referrer_code].empty?
      # This returns nil
      coupon = Coupon.find_by(code: params[:user][:referrer_code])
      params[:user][:referrer_id] = coupon.referrer_id if coupon&.referrer && coupon&.multiple?
  end
  super
end
```

Comment: If `find_by` returns `nil` it means it's not found. We can't debug that because we can't see your data or params. If it's assigning a different user than it "should" it means something isn't being set the way you expected it to be, which we also can't debug, for the same reasons.

Comment: I would agree with you BUT as I said: I copy paste code (coupon = Coupon.find_by(...)) in the byebug console and it returns object. So... I assume that's something wrong with database access for this controller (I even hardcoded 'Coupon.find(1)' and still it returns me nil

Comment: If it's part of the app it has access to the same data as any other part of the app. Byebug/pry works in the context of the controller.

Comment: Are you sure the params are going to this controller?  Can you show the params getting sent and verify the endpoint is indeed your created controller and not the devise default controller?

Comment: Yup, I'm sure. Great, now It's working somehow... All I had to do, was reset my computer and let it rest for a night (I restarted rails server multiple times, if someone asks) I even tracked down why it assigns to user ID 15 instead of user ID 3.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of changing params much better to do it this way:

```rb
def create
  super do |resource|
    if resource.persisted?
      coupon = Coupon.find_by(code: params[:user][:referrer_code])
      resource.update(referrer_id: coupon.referrer_id) if coupon&.referrer && coupon&.multiple?
    end
  end
end
```